# How to use a more recent version of a NuGet package for dependent packages in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, .net-core-3.1

I have a NuGet package that references Newtonsoft.Json v 12.0.2. I can't access the source to that NuGet package. (Technically, NuGet Package Explorer stats that it's really >= 12.0.2 )

If I wish for that package to leverage Newtonsoft.Json v 12.0.3, is it as simple as me "installing" v 12.0.3 into *my* project and all dependants (and their children, etc) which are using v 12.0.2 will now be magically using my installed 12.0.3 version?

Or does each dependency only use the version explicitly defined in their package?

What is this called? explicit referencing?

Other Info: This is for .NET Core 3.1

Comment: If you want a later version, install it explicitly. It's as simple as taht

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the new sdk project, when you install a nuget package, it will install its lowest dependencies on your project and if you want to use the higher version, you only need to install the updated dependency nuget package separately and then it will update all the dependencies to the updated version.

And it will update all dependencies of your project to that version. **Note** that it will not act on a single nuget package but all.

These two nuget packages used `Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.2` dependency

[image]

**And** if I install `Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3` nuget package separately:

[image]

They all used `Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3` and it proves that they are Shared rather than using a separate version.